# How to make HOC react app to serverside Rendering

Tags: reactjs

I want to change MY react App (Like https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedReduxCode) to Server Side Rendering

Comment: your question is vague. i suggest you read react docs on server rendering. any components can be rendered server side without having to change anything. unless you have peculiar requirement. what you need. working http server, react & react-dom library. and you are all set. just use the renderToString method.

Comment: Hii   When I change my app to SSR shows the error like   Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Header)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Header)".
   at invariant (D:\universal-react-example-master\node_modules\invariant\invariant.js:42:15)   -----What is the Solution for this(Already Have provider on router)

Comment: you need to provide store as props to the provider component ```<Provider store={ yourstorehere }><Component /></Provider>```

Comment: Already Have the store